# AfterAll global hook cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I'm using `cucumber-jvm` in my integration tests and I need to execute some code after all scenarios are finished, just once.

After reading carefully some posts like [this](http://ramblingsofaswtester.com/?p=146) and reviewed this reported [issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515), I've accomplished it doing something like this:

```
public class ContextSteps {

   private static boolean initialized = false;

   @cucumber.api.java.Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
      if (!initialized) {
         // Init context. Run just once before first scenario starts

         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // End context. Run just once after all scenarios are finished
            }
         });

         initialized = true;
      }
   }
}
```

I think the context initialization (equivalent to `BeforeAll`) done in this way is fine. However, although it's working, I'm not sure at all if the `AfterAll` simulation using `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` is a good practice.

So, these are my questions:

- Should I avoid `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` to implement `AfterAll`?
- Are there other better choices to emulate the `AfterAll` behaviour in cucumber-jvm?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a better way would be to use a build tool, like Ant, Maven or Gradle for set-up and tear-down actions, which are part of *integration tests*.

When using [Maven Fail Safe Plug-in](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html), for setting up integration tests. There is the phase `pre-integration-test`,  which is typically used for setting up the database and launch the web-container. Then the integration-tests are run (phase `integration-test`). And afterwards the phase `post-integration-test` is run, for shutting down and closing / removing / cleaning up things.

***INFO*** In case the Cucumber tests are run through JUnit, the following might also be worth considering

In case it is simpler, smaller set up stuff, you can have a look at the JUnit @BeforeClass and @AfterClass. Or implement a JUnit @ClassRule, which has it's own `before()` and `after()` methods.

```
@ClassRule
public static ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {
  @Override
  protected void before() throws Throwable {
    myServer.connect();
  }

  @Override
  protected void after() {
    myServer.disconnect();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Verhagen! Following your advices, finally I'll end up calling my class/method in `post-integration-test` phase using maven exec plugin. I agree with you that probably this would be a better choice. Just point that I'm not really sure if I can use junit annotations with cucumber-jvm. I think there are some open issues about it. Thanks again!

Comment: @troig You can use Junit annotations with Cucumber. However it will not work when using the commandline runner (because the command line ignores JUnit). This is annoying because tools like IDEA use the commandline runner.

Comment: Annotations have to be placed in the class annotated with `@RunWIth(Cucumber.java)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice @mpkorstanje

Answer (score 0):

As of Cucumber 2.4.0, the following class gave me the equivalent of @BeforeClass in Junit.

You can place this in test/java/cucumber/runtime.

```
package cucumber.runtime; //cannot change.  can be under /test/java

import cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader;
import cucumber.runtime.snippets.FunctionNameGenerator;
import gherkin.pickles.PickleStep;

import java.util.List;

public class NameThisClassWhatever implements Backend {
    private Glue glue;
    private List<String> gluePaths;

    @Override
    public void loadGlue(Glue glue, List<String> gluePaths) {
        this.glue = glue;
        this.gluePaths = gluePaths;

        //Any before steps here
    }

    @Override
    public void disposeWorld() {
        //any after steps here
    }

    @Override
    public void setUnreportedStepExecutor(UnreportedStepExecutor executor) { }

    @Override
    public void buildWorld() { }

    @Override
    public String getSnippet(PickleStep p, String s, FunctionNameGenerator fng) {
        return null;
    }

    public NameThisClassWhatever(ResourceLoader resourceLoader)  { }
}
```

Comment: This is very fragile and should not be relied upon. There is no guarantee that this will happen only once. This will for instance break when running in parallel with 4.0.