# How to achieve BeforeSuite functionality in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am new to Cucumber and getting acquainted with it.

But in my framework i have @Before and @After methods, which executes before & after every scenario.

But i need to little cleaning before my scenarios getting executed. For that i want a similar functionality of @BeforeSuite from TestNG.

Can someone help to get the pointers about it?

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563261/afterall-global-hook-cucumber-jvm) could help you

Answer (score 2):

If your suite is defined by one runner you can use the simple jUnit `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You need Extended Cucumber Runner.

http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/extended-cucumber-runner

Literally does what it says on the tin... Extension of standard cucumber that provides beforesuite and aftersuite methods.

EDIT: More detailed usage of using the Beforesuite and Aftersutie methods.

http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/before-after-methods

Hope this helps.

Comment: Before i post the question here, i looked into this topic, but unable to understand how to use it. Following is my runner. @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
   features={"src/test/resource"}
//   tags={"@Temp"}
  )
public class RunnerTest 
{

}
This statement in their post "The above annotations should be applied to the main test class where ExtendedCucumber runner is applied to. " is most confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cucumber with TestNG, please have a look at this repository to get started : https://github.com/igniteram/testng-cucumber. It has all the necessary methods **Before/AfterSuite** hooks that you are looking for! just an example.

Answer (score 0):

As of Cucumber 2.4.0 if you add the following class and it should work:

You can place this in test/java/cucumber/runtime.

```
package cucumber.runtime; //cannot change.  can be under /test/java

import cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader;
import cucumber.runtime.snippets.FunctionNameGenerator;
import gherkin.pickles.PickleStep;

import java.util.List;

public class NameThisClassWhatever implements Backend {
    private Glue glue;
    private List<String> gluePaths;

    @Override
    public void loadGlue(Glue glue, List<String> gluePaths) {
        this.glue = glue;
        this.gluePaths = gluePaths;

        //Any before steps here
    }

    @Override
    public void disposeWorld() {
        //any after steps here
    }

    @Override
    public void setUnreportedStepExecutor(UnreportedStepExecutor executor) { }

    @Override
    public void buildWorld() { }

    @Override
    public String getSnippet(PickleStep p, String s, FunctionNameGenerator fng) {
        return null;
    }

    public NameThisClassWhatever(ResourceLoader resourceLoader)  { }
}
```