# Cucumber +Maven+TestNG

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

@BeforeMethod is not executing after execution of @Test in cucumber with TestNG

I have integrated maven with cucumber and written script using TestNG.
I have added necessary dependency in pom.xml
When I execute the script @BeforeMethod is not working after execution of @Test
Can you tell me whether TesNG annotations are supported or not?.
Kindly can you guide me on this.

Runner class:

```
package Maveneditinv;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;


@CucumberOptions(features="Editfeaturefile"  , glue = {"Stepdefinition"} , tags={"@SmokeTest , @FunctionalTest"} )
public class learn_cucmber_invTest  extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {





}
```

Step definition :

```
public class logininv {

    public static WebDriver d;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;


    @Test(priority =1, enabled = true)
    @When("^user enters duplicates email id in add new client corresponding error messages should be thrown$")
      public void addclient1() throws InterruptedException {
          Cliendaddimage obj3 = PageFactory.initElements(d, Cliendaddimage.class);
          obj3.img1();
          obj3.clientdetails("TQ 71", "TQ 71", "test.igs1@gmail.com", "test.igs1@gmail.com" , "test.igs@yahoo.com");
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          jse = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
          jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          obj3.updateclick();
          obj3.payterm("Term 12");
          jse = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
          jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
          obj3.updateclick1();


      }



    @Test(priority=2, enabled = true)
      @When("^Should select client from drop-down and updated$")
        public void selectclientfromdrpdown1() {

          Clientdropdown1 obj4 = PageFactory.initElements(d,Clientdropdown1.class);
          obj4.clientdrp1("VK 03");
          jse = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
          jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
          obj4.clientdrp2();

      }




      @BeforeMethod
        @When("^user clicks on edit invoie link$")
        public void i_click_on_edit_invoice_link() throws InterruptedException{

                                              Thread.sleep(5000);
                                                          manageinv obj1 = PageFactory.initElements(d, manageinv.class);
                    obj1.editinvoices();

        }



    @BeforeClass
    @When(value="I enter username and password")
    public void Open_handdy_login_page() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium jars\\Selenium jar new\\geckodriver.exe");
          d = new FirefoxDriver();


    }
```

Expection: @Beforemethod should be executed after every @Test

Actual: @Beforemethod is not working after execution of @Test

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `@Test` annotations on the step as they are step and not test! This is not the way cucumber test are written. Cucumber is runner for test authored in Gherkin. This [tutorial](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) will help you understand. Your bdd should look like below:

```
Scenario: name of scenario
Given I enter username and password
When user clicks on edit invoie link
Then Should select client from drop-down and updated
```

However if you want to [use different listener from TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991190/cucumber-jvm-after-with-appium-driver/54045361#54045361) you should use [QAF](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki) which is [TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks).

Comment: As I wrote, I have feature files with steps etc. I want to have not only by feature file. I want to have Both(feature with steps and @Test in same project)